# Moving out [transition]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/transition/info) for [transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) reads:

> Using javascript or css to animate an element from one position to another.

However, of the 50 questions on the front page:

- **17 questions (34%)** are about transitions on Android and should be using  [android-transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-transitions) or another more specific tag.
- **11 questions (22%)** are related to animating using the API of a specific JavaScript library.
- **10 questions (20%)** are about CSS and are or should be [css-transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transitions)
- **9 questions (18%)** are about transitions on iOS and should be using [ios-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-animations) or [core-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-animation) or another tag relating to Apple's APIs.
- **3 questions (6%)** are about making the transition from one technology to another. Lots of these are already closed. Anyway, they shouldn't be tagged with animation.

  So,

  **58%** of the above (mostly Android/iOS) have nothing to do with the tag wiki.

  **6%** are questions that have nothing to do with animation.

---

I don't think this tag gives any benefit at all by grouping together questions about animating from one state to another. If this was [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) or [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags) it would be great, but every environment is going to have its own APIs for transitions and an expert in one is not really going to translate over.

And the tag has less than a dozen followers.

---

Maybe it should be removed completely and its questions retagged?

Comment: The tag wiki is also wrong...it's about animating an element from one *state* to another.

Comment: "3 questions... Lots of these..." That feels like a contradiction.

Answer (score 31):

This tag is ambiguous and will never be anything but a meta-tag.

Unfortunately 95% of posters do not take note of the tag wiki and will string together multiple meta tags which in conjunction make sense but each separately do not.

It should be destroyed as being a meta-tag and black listed because it lacks discriminatory power.
It is simply too vague to be useful as is evident in the usage listed in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I whole-heartedly agree. We should start with a retag of the big ones.

Action Items:

1. Change the tag wiki ✔️
2. Automatically retag all [1,766 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition+css) with [transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) and ([css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) ||[sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass)) to [css-transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transitions)
3. Automatically retag all [450 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition+android) with [transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) and [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) to [android-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-animation)
4. Automatically retag all 485 questions with [transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) and ([ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) || [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)) to [ios-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-animations)
5. Automatically retag all [382 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition+d3.js) with [transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) and [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js)to [d3.js-transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-transitions)
6. Automatically retag all 139 questions with [transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) and ([vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) ||
   [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2)) to [vue-transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-transitions)
7. Automatically retag all 81 questions with [transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) and ([angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) ||
   [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)) to [angular-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-animations)
8. Automatically retag all [16 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition+flutter) with [transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) and [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) to [flutter-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-animation)
9. Come up with solutions for the remaining [1569 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition%2B-swift%2B-ios%2B-android%2B-css%2B-sass%2B-vue.js%2B-vuejs2%2B-flutter%2B-d3.js%2B-angular%2B-angularjs)

Answer (score -2):

We should just merge it with [transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transitions).

Our documentation spells it out quite clearly:

> Transitions are a progression from one state to another, often in user interfaces or state-machines.

This seems to be exactly how you describe people are currently using [transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition).

Comment: Why was this answer deemed not useful by two people...?

Comment: I think because [tag:transitions] is already a synonym of [tag:transition]

Comment: @LeoDog896 you're observing the change which was made as a result of this question, which was asked 6 years ago and I believe enacted upon 2 years ago, whereas my concern you're responding to occurred 4 years ago